# Make sure I get security updates for kernel 2.6.32 on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have an old CentOS 6 server that I want to update from CentOS 6.3 to CentOS 6.9

Since CentOS came with kernel 2.6.32 (which reached out of life in Feb 2016), I did research on whether I should upgrade the kernel to 4.x. I came across two answers:

1. It's not a good idea to upgrade CentOS/RHEL to a different Kernel, as that may affect stability
2. RH are backporting security updates and bug fixes for their 2.6.32 kernel.
   My question is: Which repos should I be using to run my updates after all these years, and how do I check if I got the "backported" updates for 2.6.32

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> how do I check if I got the "backported" updates for 2.6.32

You can read the changes in the Changelog : The file kernel.spec in the SRPM: Lines 1,742 ..    ~47,000.

Current is version 2.6.32-**696.1.1**.el6  http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Workstation/en/os/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.src.rpm

All versions, SRPM http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Workstation/en/os/SRPMS/